# Setting a plain background color for a QGraphicsView widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator, qt-designer

I'm trying to display a little square of solid color.

I've created a QGraphicsView widget myGraphicsView and call:

```
ui->myGraphicsView->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt::red, Qt::SolidPattern));
```

But it stays white. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the QGraphicsScene to the QGraphicsView before anything is drawn:

```
ui->myGraphicsView->setScene(myScene);
```